# Authenticating using MSAL.js in azure webapp

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-msal

I have tried implementing MSAL into a webapp I'm developing, but I've run into some issues, especially with IE and Edge.

The first issue arrises in both chrome and IE/Edge. Upon login I get 2 popups. Before the second popup concludes, the program have already called the Graph API and returned data, so why it shows, I do not know. The code is as follows:

```
function login(){
    clientApplication = clientApplication || new Msal.UserAgentApplication({ClientId}, null, function (errorDes, token, error, tokenType) {});

    clientApplication.loginPopup(["user.read files.readwrite.all group.readwrite.all"]).then(function (token) {
        getAccessToken();
    }, function (error) {
        // handle error
    });
}

function getAccessToken() {
    clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(["user.read files.readwrite.all group.readwrite.all"]).then(function (token) {
        //Call Graph API and do stuff.
    });
}
```

Apart from showing 2 popups, this works perfectly in chrome. If I leave out any of this, I will not be authenticated.

Now, the second part is a but more problematic. I have included the polyfill for promises to make it work in IE, but I still encounter something wierd. If I do not disable Protected Mode in IE, both popups open, but the first one redirects to https://{site}.azurewebsites.net/null . The second popup redirects to about:blank. Neither windows closes, as would be expected.

However, if I do disable Protected Mode, as suggested in the MSAL.js documentation for internal testing, I do get authenticated - the popups just doesn't close automatically. This is obviously not a viable solution for a multi-tenant webapp..

Is there something really wrong about my authentication flow, or am I just missing something? Is there any decent documentation of running authentication with MSAL.js in a single page applicaiton?

EDIT: After some digging, I've found that the authflow is also started in the iframe that is used to make the silent calls. Is there any reason the entire page is also loaded in said iframe? It run all my functions that is run when the dom is ready..

It appears as if no calls are silent, but always requires a popup..

Comment: Have you maybe found more information about this topic?

Comment: I'm afraid I have not.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if the issue is with your OS, your browsers, your application or the libraries. Can you please verify the folloing?
1. Do you have the same issue when trying to run the following sample? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-graphapi-v2 ?

2. which version of your OS/Browser do you use?

Comment: Let me guess - you invoke MSAL automatically during page load, and the RedirectUri of your registered app is pointing to the same page, correct?

The OAuth endpoint needs to send the id_token or access_token back, and that's done by pointing the current window's location back to the RedirectUri.

In your case, after the first login, the pop up windows gets pointed back to your main page, and your auth flow gets triggered again, so - multiple popups.

Comment: You can:
1. Set up a dedicated page for the auth callback, and update your app RedirectUri to it. UserAgentApplication needs to know the RedirectUri as well - the current NPM version of msal doesn't support it but the newest Github version does.
2. Modify your page to stop triggering the auth flow during the callback. Try to UserAgentApplication.IsCallback function for the check since there are multiple callback scenarios.

In general, I found MSAL not very ideal, especially the popup flow. It doesn't work if user blocks popup, and might not work when 3rd party cookie is disabled.

Comment: @sidecus I'm not sure what version of MSAL you were referring to, but it would appear that v.0.1.3 does not have an `IsCallback` function.  Do you know of another way to check for callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Adding below URL in the "Trusted Sites" under "Security" inside "Internet Options" solved the problem

**login.microsoftonline.com**

Got the hint from ADAL JS Git doc: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js#trusted-site-settings-in-ie

Of course it will need to be done on every user's machine. As it was internal website for us, we have asked our IT department to add policy to push this particular setting on machines of all users.

Comment: Isn't that only an option for IE? I don't think Edge had an option to set trusted sites.